# Show that a space is a probability space.

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative random variable defined on a probability space $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$ with $E[|X|]<\infty $. For $A\in F$ define:
$$Q[A]=\frac{E[X \chi_A]}{E[X]}$$
where $\chi_A$ is the indicator(characteristic) function of A. Is $(\Omega, F, Q)$ a probability space?

What we need to show is that $Q$ is a probability measure, so we have to check the three properties: non-negativity, normalization and countable additivity. I already checked the first two but I have no idea how to prove the last part.

Could anyone help?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? A (probability) measure has to satisfy certain properties, so... what about checking them?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. I am stuck on showing the countable additivity of the measure.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but it's a little strange how $\chi$ is rendered there. It looks like a subscript of $X$ (but it's not). Even in my comment here, the $\chi$ is noticeably lower the rest of the text. Is this just $\LaTeX$ renders $\chi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $A_i$ are disjoint and $A$ is their union, then $1_A = \sum 1_{A_i}$.
Since $X$ is nonnegative 
$$E[X1_A] = E[X \sum_{i=1}^\infty 1_{A_i}] 1_{A_i}] =E[\lim_{N\to\infty}X \sum_{i=1}^N 1_{A_i}]= \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N E[X 1_{A_i}] =\sum_{i=1}^\infty E[X 1_{A_i}]$$

where here we have applied the monotone convergence theorem since the partial sums are increasing.